# Expanded widget inside ListViewBuilder giving "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget" error

Tags: flutter, listview

I have a Container inside a list view builder and I want this container to be dynamic in size according to the size of child of container (here  textwidget), so I used expanded widget for container but it gave an error:

> incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

```
List<String> values = [
    "short text",
    "long textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong text"
  ];
```

```
body: ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount: values.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Expanded(
          child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    blurRadius: 2.0,
                    spreadRadius: 0.0,
                    offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              child: Text(values[index])),
        );
      }),
```

I want the container to expand according to the size of text in list of strings.

Comment: There is no need to use expanded because container will automatic take its child's space, so remove Expanded widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just remove Expanded and give some padding to the container. like below

```
ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: values.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey,
                blurRadius: 2.0,
                spreadRadius: 0.0,
                offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Text(values[index]));
    }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
List<String> values = [
    "short text",
    "long textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong textlong text"
  ];
 body: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: values.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    boxShadow: const [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        blurRadius: 2.0,
                        spreadRadius: 0.0,
                        offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Text(values[index]));
          }),
```